# How can I prevent a table within a list from continuing the numbering scheme?

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm writing a list of steps for some documentation, and want a simple table to show some settings based on conditions.  The problem is that Word is adding a number to each cell in the table, when the table itself should just be part of the list item.  How do I make the table itself be part of the list item, instead of each cell part of the list?

Comment: Ok, so a minute later I figure out you can just hit backspace in each cell to delete the numbering... but leaving the question in case there is a better/more correct way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- I typically add the list item where I want the table (*current item*), enter the text there (not the table yet), then add the *next item* (to go after the table) and add some text there.
- I would then return to my *current item* (where the table goes) hit `Enter` (which would add a new item between the *current* and the *next*, and then delete this newly added item with `Backspace` which would break the list giving me a new paragraph under the *current* item to work with, and leaving the *next* item with the current number on it.
- Now all I need to do is insert the table in the paragraph after my *current* item and it will stay there nicely without messing up the numbered list with correct indent as well.

Hopefully, such explanation makes sense to you. The main advantage over your option is that you are not dependent on the number of rows n your table which you have to fix once the table is simply dumped into the list.